# Check if emulator is using kvm in android studio

Tags: android-emulator

I have followed all the instructions [from here](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#vm-linux) and [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator) for enabling kvm for android studio to enable vm acceleration.

Still I suspect that when I start android studio it isn't using kvm because on starting it, in the `Run` box at the bottom the command executed is

> /root/Android/Sdk/tools/emulator -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_21_x86

I don't see the `-qemu -m 512 -enable-kvm` option appended to it. Is there a way to check if it's actually using vm acceleration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just checked if the file /dev/kvm was opened before and after the emulator started:

```
sudo lsof -n | grep /dev/kvm
```

Comment: Good, but sudo is not needed.